# How to use a list of items (heriting from an abstract class) as its abstract class?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, abstraction

Here's a short example of the issue I'm encountering

I have two abstract classes EntityAbs and ListEntityAbs :

```cs
public abstract class EntityAbs {
    //Save itself in a Database
    public abstract int SaveEntity();
}
public abstract class ListEntitiesAbs<T> where T : EntityAbs {
    protected List<T> InnerList;

    //Save each values in a Database
    public virtual int SaveEntities()
    {
        return InnerList.Sum(entity => entity.SaveEntity());
    }
}
```

Multiple classes that herits on EntityAbs and get it's own ListEntities (an example with a class named Item) :

```cs
public class Item : EntityAbs {
    public override int SaveEntity()
    {
        // Implements here how I save it
    }
}
public class Items : ListEntitiesAbs<Item>, IList<Item> { 
    // Has specific class stuff in it
}
```

Now, I would like to save every ListEntitiesAbs *somewhere else* on my database

```cs
public int Save(params ListEntitiesAbs<EntityAbs>[] lists)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
        lists[i].SaveEntities();
}

Items items = new Items();
// add items 
int result = Save(items);
```

But then, items (or any other list I add here) displays an error by Visual Studio, and I don't here why.
The error says that it `Cannot convert from Items to ListEntitiesAbs<EntityAbs>`, but Items herits from ListEntitiesAbs and Item from EntityAbs..

Am I missing something ? I've tried casting as ListEntityAbs or using Cast<> but nothing fits

Any help is appreciated, as I'm not even sure if this kind of behavior is actually possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `ListEntitiesAbs<T>` is not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces). This means that `ListEntitiesAbs<Item>` is not, and cannot be trivially converted to, `ListEntitiesAbs<EntityAbs>`.

Option 1: make `Save` generic

```
public int Save<T>(params ListEntitiesAbs<T>[] lists) where T:EntityAbs 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
       lists[i].SaveEntities();
}
```

Option 2: non generic interface. You could also make a covariant interface, but that does not seem to be needed in this particular case.

```
public interface IListEntitiesAbs {
    public int SaveEntities();
}
public int Save(params IListEntitiesAbs[] lists){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is exactly what I needed, and I feel ashamed not thinking about it. It solves my compatibility issue, but then `params` doesn't seem to work if I add multiple lists when I call the `Save()` method, do you have any other clues ?

Comment: @arrcival `params` should work just fine with generic methods. A guess is that the types do not match, i.e. you are trying to call `Save(new ListEntitiesAbs<Item>(), new ListEntitiesAbs<EntityAbs>())` This will not work for the reason stated above. If this is a problem, use option 2 instead.

Comment: This is a .NET fiddle based on my example https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqPglu .  I guess none of those solutions works and I'll have to go with the option 2